# Exception in thread “AWT-EventQueue-0” java.lang.NullPointerException on click on JButton to INSERT IN DATABASE

Tags: java, database, swing, nullpointerexception, jframe

I am new to java and JDBC usage. I am writing my first java application that connects to database. But i am getting this error when i click on th JButton that performs the INSERT. But i get this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at controlbiblioteca.Conexion.execute(Conexion.java:39)
    at controlbiblioteca.InsertarPrestamo.btnInsertarActionPerformed(InsertarPrestamo.java:96)
    at controlbiblioteca.InsertarPrestamo.access$000(InsertarPrestamo.java:9)
    at controlbiblioteca.InsertarPrestamo$1.actionPerformed(InsertarPrestamo.java:66)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

In Conexion.java:39 i have this:

```
Statement instruccion;
        try {
            instruccion = myConn.createStatement();   //line39
            instruccion.executeUpdate(sql);
            
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error al ejecutar la instruccion");
            System.out.println(ex);
            System.exit(0);
            
        }
```

In the Jbutton i wrote this code.

```
if(txtIDuser.getText().isEmpty()|| txtIDejemplar.getText().isEmpty()|| txtFechpres.getText().isEmpty()|| txtFechdev.getText().isEmpty())
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Favor de llenar todos los campos");
        }        
        else
        {
            Conexion c = new Conexion();
            c.execute("INSERT INTO prestamo VALUES ("+txtIDuser.getText()+", "+txtIDejemplar.getText()+", '"+txtFechpres.getText()+"', '"+txtFechdev.getText()+"' );");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Insercion realizada correctamente","Exito!",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
```

And in the class named Bibliotecaria the private connection variable is not used apparently.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1HIo.png)

Comment: The `myConn` variable is null.

Comment: See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) & [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/418556)